# select all table cells starting with character

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am receiving external tabular data which I'm dumping into an HTML table. Their system starts each table header row with a dash e.g "-Lorem ipsum". I wrote the following snippet to embolden the headings but it's not working - I must be missing something!

```
$(".csvTable td").each(function () 
{    
    var cellValue = $(this).text();

    if (cellValue.indexOf("-")) 
        $(this).wrapInner( "<strong></strong>");
});
```

(it's rendered with PHP, so if you think it'd be better handled there then please share!)

Comment: try this cellValue.indexOf("-") == 0

Comment: correct! ha I thought 0 was implicit. submit as a proper answer and I'll accept your answer. many thanks!

Comment: Will make an answer so you can close this question..

Comment: Just a completely umrelated .indexOf tip: instead of `strOrArray.indexOf("-") != -1`, which is quite commonly used to check if a string is in the string/array, you can also do `~strOrArray.indexOf("-")`. That `~` will perform a bitwise NOT, so -1 becomes 0, which is interpreted as `false` and all other values will become something other than 0, so they're interpreted as `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in comments, try this:

```
cellValue.indexOf("-") == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, `indexOf` returns an index if found, or -1 if not.

If you want to know if it **starts with** that character, say if value.indexOf("-") == 0.

And yes, I think you should use PHP. It would look like this:

```
if (strpos($val, "-") === 0) {
   $val = "<strong>$val</strong>";
}
```

Comment: @felixthehat no prob. :)